# How to utilize vim's syntax color to replace the `highlight' utility?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, pipe

I feel that the `highlight' utility doesn't support as many file types as vim does, and the project isn't very active. 
When the file is gzipped, highlight doesn't recognize it at all.

But in despite of `highlight', as an alternative choice, can I have the colorized vim text output to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `vim` for this you can disable clearing of the screen on exit with `:set t_ti= t_te=`.

To make this behave a little more light `highlight` you can automatically exit `vim`. This will however only show you one screen of higlighted source. Additionally you would need to `:redraw` the screen to actually see something.

Also use the `view` alias of `vim` to open the file read-only.

```
$ view --cmd "set t_ti= t_te=" "+redraw" "+q" YOUR_FILE
```

A way more natural solution would [`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) from the pygments python package.

Comment: Well, the usage only gives one screen, but at least it gives one screen.

What I want is to utilize the highlight function of vim, maybe I have to hack into the source code.

Answer (score 3):

vim can act as a replacement for `less`, while adding features such as vim's syntax highlighting, by running `/usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/macros/less.sh`.

I haven't used `highlight`, so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.

Comment: You can use the `-n` flag to ignore the case when the file is already open in another vim window and has a swap file.
My `.bashrc` - `alias vless='/usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/less.sh -n'`